# Самое маленькое целое число, при котором будет последовательность натуральных чисел

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

> [4,3,6]

здесь самое маленькое целое число это - 5, при котором у нас будет массив

> [3,4,5,6]

который последовательность натуральных чисел.

Здесь-

> [2,4,6,8]

самое маленькое целое число, который отсутствует это - 3

А здесь - 1

> [-1,-2]

Нужно написать функцию JavaScript, который будет возвращать самое маленькое целое число, который отсутствует в массиве.

Еще примеры массивов и ответов - [-3,-4,-5]-1, [-1,-2,1,7,4]-2, [1,2,3,6,8]-4 и т.д.

У меня такая программа, который видимо не так уж правильный.

```js
    function solution(x){
    let n;
    let m;
    let y=x.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (y[i]>y[i-1]!=1) {
          n = y[i]-y[i-1];
          let k = 1
          if (n>=1) {
              m = y[i-1]+k;
          }
          else {
            return k
          }         
        } 
      } 
      return m;   
    }
    console.log(solution([-1,-2,1,3]))
```

Comment: Тема вопроса не соответствует содержанию.

Comment: Поясните, почему для `[1,2,3,6,8]` должно получиться 5, а не 4?

Comment: простите,вы правы,будет 4.

Comment: Что ожидается от этого условия . ``if (y[i]>y[i-1]!=1)``?

Comment: ну это в начале я неправильно думал)

Comment: Ну так если думал неправильно, а теперь стал думать правильно, то значит надо и код изменить на правильный. Может быть, тогда и проблема исчезнет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function solution(arr) {
  let a = arr.filter(n => n > 0)
    .sort((a, b) => a-b)
    .reduce((acc, n, i, arr) => {
      if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
        acc.push(arr[i])
      } 
      return acc;
    }, []);
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] + 1 != a[i+1]) return a[i] + 1;
  }
  return 1;
}

console.log(solution([4, 3, 6])); // 5
console.log(solution([2, 4, 6, 8])); // 3 
console.log(solution([-1, -2])); // 1
console.log(solution([-3, -4, -5])); // 1
console.log(solution([-1, -2, 1, 7, 4])); // 2
console.log(solution([1, 2, 3, 6, 8])); // 4
console.log(solution([2, 2])); // 3
console.log(solution([2, 2, 3])); // 4
```

Надо заметить, что тут используется сомнительная практика обращения к элементам массива за пределами этого массива. Лучше так не делать. :)

Comment: спасибо большое,очень помогли)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала создаем список с числами больше 0, а потом рекурсивно ищем минимальное число. Решение не требует сортировки и работает за время `O(n)`

```js
const findMinNumber = (list, min) => {
  if (!list[min]) return 1;
  if (list[min].next) {
    return findMinNumber(list, list[min].next);
  }
  return min + 1;
};

const solution = (arr) => {
  let min = Infinity;
  const list = {};
  for (const number of arr) {
    if (number > 0) {
      if (number < min) {
        min = number;
      }
      list[number] = {};
      if (list[number - 1]) {
        list[number - 1].next = number;
      }
      if (list[number + 1]) {
        list[number].next = number + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return findMinNumber(list, min);
}

console.log(solution([4, 3, 6])); // 5
console.log(solution([2, 4, 6, 8])); // 3 
console.log(solution([-1, -2])); // 1
console.log(solution([-3, -4, -5])); // 1
console.log(solution([-1, -2, 1, 7, 4])); // 2
console.log(solution([1, 2, 3, 6, 8])); // 4
console.log(solution([2, 2])); // 3
console.log(solution([2, 2, 3])); // 4
```